# Is it normal that my function onNewToken is never called?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the firebase procedure in order to implement my firebase notification with cloud messaging but it is not working

My log in the onNewToken() function is never called

I have the version 19.0.1 for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1 and 17.0.1 for com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1

I tried to take the token manually with this :

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {
            sendTokenNotification(it.token)
        }
```

But with this, the notification I = s never send in the background... Only when I open my App

In my AndroidManifest, I have

```
<service
            android:name="library.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
```

In my MainActivity, I have in my onCreate

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.w("NEW_TOKEN", "getInstanceId failed", task.exception)
                        return@OnCompleteListener
                    }

                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    val token = task.result?.token

                    // Log and toast
                    val msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token)
                    Log.d("NEW_TOKEN", msg)
                })

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled = true
```

And in my MyFirebaseMessagingService I have :

```java
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("", "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.v("NEW_TOKEN",s);

        sendTokenNotification(s);
    }
```

And it never shows the Log in my onNewToken()

I don't have any error it's just not entering my function

So I was wondering if I do something wrong ...

(I don't know if it can be this but my MainActivity is in Kotlin and my FirebaseMessagingService in java)

Comment: It will be called whenever a new token is generated for your application.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply ^^ I didn't understand that the token was genereted only the first time you launch the app ^^ my problem is on my API now ^^ thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you want to generate a token every time?